# CSS adding social icons next to text

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/pnwyuyed/)

I need to add social icons next text "follow us".

And I have to work with each link. but i have only one image..

So i need to set position something like that.but i just confused how to set.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="social-bar">        
      <p class="follow-us">Follow Us</p>
      <a>
        <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/63sed3cjn/social_icons.png" />
     </a>    
  </div>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this,?

Thanks,

Comment: How does your CSS look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `background-image`. [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s4hmq2s/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="social-bar">
  <p class="follow-us">
    <span class="follow">Follow Us</span>
    <a href="#" class="social fb"></a>
    <a href="#" class="social twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="social google"></a>
    <a href="#" class="social pinterest"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.social-bar{
  border-top:1px solid red;
  width:922px;
  background-color:#ef9d9d;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e48181; 
  height:49px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position: relative;
}
.social-bar p{
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:16px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.social {
    background-image: url(http://s13.postimg.org/63sed3cjn/social_icons.png);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.social.twitter {
    background-position: -35px 0;
}

.social.google {
    background-position: -70px 0;
}

.social.pinterest {
    background-position: -100px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Instead of <p> use span tag
 <div class="social-bar">

    <span class="follow-us">Follow Us</span>
      <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/63sed3cjn/social_icons.png" /></a>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

vertical-align: super;
  display: inline-block; add this lines in your .social-bar p. Then it will work